# Mirror momentum in a Mach-Zehnder interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, reflection, interference

As I understand it, the mirrors in a MZI should gain momentum from the reflected photons. How much momentum should the mirrors get for a single photon?  In a simple photon-mirror incident at $\pi/4$ it should be $2h/\sqrt{2}\nu$ if I'm thinking correctly.  So in MZI should the mirrors get $\pm h/\sqrt{2}\nu$?

Comment: I've never heard of an MZI where this effect was significant compared to other uncertainties like acoustic noise and air turbulence.